Does Solution to Banach Space ODE $\dot{x} = Ax$ with Non-Positive Spectrum Converges to Kernel?
Let $A:X \rightarrow X$ be a bounded linear Banach space operator. In this book, Daleckii and Krein investigate the behavior of the initial value problem $\dot{x} = Ax$ with $x(0) = x_0$ in terms of the spectrum $\sigma(A)$. They show that $x(t) = e^{At}x_0$ is the general solution to this IVP. A key result of theirs is that if $\text{Re}(\lambda) < 0$ for all $\lambda \in \sigma(A)$, then the asymptotic behavior of the solution is that $x(t) \rightarrow 0$ as $t \rightarrow \infty$.
I am interested in what happens when we allow $0$ to be in the spectrum. To keep things simple, let’s phrase my question like this:
Question: Suppose $A: X \rightarrow X$ is a bounded Banach space operator with $\sigma(A) \subseteq [-M, 0]$. Does $x(t) = e^{At}x_0$ converge to an element of $\ker(A)$ for all $x_0 \in X$?
I have some partial results in this direction. First, if $X$ is a separable Hilbert space, and $A$ is self-adjoint, then the spectral theorem can be used to show that $x(t) \rightarrow \pi x_0$, where $\pi:X \rightarrow X$ is the orthogonal projection onto $\ker(A)$.
Second, the result of Daleckii and Krein can be used in some cases. For example, suppose that $\ker(A)$ is a complemented subspace of $X$, and we can write $X = \ker(A) \oplus Y$ for some other closed subspace $Y$. If $\text{Image}(A) \subseteq Y$, then we get convergence to something in the kernel. We can show this by writing $x(t) = x_1(t) + x_2(t)$, with $x_1 \in \ker(A)$ and $x_2 \in W$. $x_1(t) = x_1(0)$ does not move, while $x_2(t) \rightarrow 0$ by the result of Daleckii and Krein.
I am not convinced that this should work in general though.
For example, to disprove the general result, I think it would suffice to find a bounded operator $A:X \rightarrow X$ with $\sigma(A) \subseteq [-M,0]$ for which $\ker(A)$ is not complemented in $X$. Suppose we had such an $A$, and for all $x \in X$, we have that $e^{At}x$ converges to an element in $\ker(A)$ as $t \rightarrow \infty$. Then the map $\phi:X \rightarrow A$ defined by $\phi(x) := \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} e^{At}x$ would be an idempotent linear map. I think that $\phi$ would also be bounded (this should follow from continuity of $A$ but I haven’t proven it). This would make $\phi$ a projection map onto $\ker(A)$, and thus $A$ would need to be complemented.
However, I have no idea how to find such an operator $A$. Non-complemented subspaces get weird. However, I did find a result here that if $X$ is a separable Banach space, then every subspace $N \subseteq X$ can be realized as the kernel of some map $A: X \rightarrow X$. However, I had difficulty figuring out the spectrum of the map constructed.
Any help (0r references!) would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

No. Consider the case $X = \mathbb{R}^2$ and the system
$$
\begin{aligned}
x_1' &= x_2 \\
x_2' &= 0.
\end{aligned}
$$
The kernel of the operator $A = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ is $\mathrm{span}\{e_1\}$ and the spectrum is $\{0\}$, but $e^{tA} = \begin{pmatrix}1 & t \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$. We can then see that any solution with initial condition $x_2(0)\neq0$ will not be in the kernel and will not converge to an element of it.

Oh shoot I didn’t even consider simple, finite dimensional counterexamples.

Wow I am actually so embarrassed by this. Thank you again.

There is no need to be embarrassed! Center manifolds are weird objects even in finite dimensions
